# Perl JSON encode creates json array from single key

Tags: json, perl

Using Perl to encode hash to be use by Java program.
The JSON encode converts a single key to JSON array element.

```
my %attribute;
push (@{$attribute {"Color"}},'Green');
push (@{$attribute {"Model"}}, ('Model_1','Model_2'));
print Dumper(\%attribute);
my $json_attr = JSON->new->utf8->encode(\%attribute);
print $json_attr;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'Model' => [
        'Model_1',
        'Model_2'
        ],
    'Color' => [
        'Green'
        ]
};
{"Model":["Model_1","Model_2"],"Color":["Green"]}
```

I need that the single key in the hash will look like this: **{"Color":"Green"}** (without the square brackets)
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First you create an array, and want it looks like not array? May be not create it? No array = no problems.

```
$attribute{'Color'} = 'Green';
```

But if you really need to do this you can use map:

```
%attribute = map {
   $_, @{$attribute{$_}} == 1 ? $attribute{$_}[0] : $attribute{$_}
} keys %attribute;
```